# Flutter: The following assertion was thrown during performResize(): Vertical viewport was given unbounded height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

Super newbie to coding and learning Flutter.

Trying to do a template post in Flutter for a newsfeed of an app that will call data from cloud.

No flagged errors in the dart code, but returns **"Vertical Viewport was given unbounded height."** when ran. Code is below.[Only appbar appears. body always blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX08u.jpg)

```js
class Post extends StatelessWidget {
  final Post post;
  Post({newsfeed.post});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          elevation: 8.0,
          shadowColor: Colors.grey,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
          child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: ListTile(
                      leading: CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 20.0,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(post.userimage),
                      ),
                      title: Text(
                        post.username,
                      ),
                      subtitle: Text("Post Date"),
                      trailing:
                          Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.purple[600]),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Row(children: [
                Container(
                  width: 250.0,
                  height: 200.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        fit: BoxFit.cover, image: NetworkImage(post.postimage)),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.textcomment, color: Colors.purple[600]),
                    Text(post.intcomments.toString()),
                    SizedBox(width: 20),
                    Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.purple[600]),
                    SizedBox(width: 20),
                    Text(post.intlikes.toString()),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              ]),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by setting width at `ListTile` and replacing `ListView` with Column on `Card` will fixed this issue. while using network images on web try to with `specific render option` like `flutter run -d c --web-renderer html`

check this soulution [updated]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Post extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            columnItem(constraints),
            columnItem(constraints),
            columnItem(constraints),
            columnItem(constraints),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Card columnItem(BoxConstraints constraints) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 8.0,
      shadowColor: Colors.grey,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
          20.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                //removing extra padding
                width: constraints.maxWidth - 30,
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    ///for netWork
                    radius: 20,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                      "https://www.rd.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/01-shutterstock_476340928-Irina-Bg-1024x683.jpg",
                    ),
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    "Name here ",
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text("Post Date"),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.purple[600]),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 250.0,
                height: 200.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    image: AssetImage("assets/image.jpg"),
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.ac_unit, color: Colors.purple[600]),
                  Text("heiya "),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Icon(Icons.favorite, color: Colors.purple[600]),
                  SizedBox(width: 20),
                  Text("hi asddddddddddda"),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: hello @Yeasin, thank you for your quick help! really appreciate it. Was able to make some of the content to appear. There are still some glitches though, the CircleAvatar NetworkImage doesn't appear but the post's image appears. And the list doesn't scroll (there is a lot of sample json posts in the cloud but only 2 appear). Hope you can answer my questions. Thank you so much :)

Comment: hello @Yeasin, the whole body became blank and returned only the "else if, return "error" when I used the updated code.  I'm not familiar with Sliver List, can the newsfeed be achieved with a SingleChildScrollView widget instead? Thank you so much... T_T

Comment: hi @Yeasin, the updated code worked already. thank you very much ^_^